# Sharepoint 2013 Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-2013, internet-explorer-11

I am working with Sharepoint 2013 and I developed some app parts to show information in our intranet.  These app parts get data from WEB API using  Jquery, It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, but in Internet Explorer 11 does not work.

For example:
[Example using developer tool in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0oCW.png)

And in Chrome it works fine (in Firefox too)

[Example using developer tools in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIYaR.png)

I developed these app parts in a remote session in Sharepoint server 2013 (Windows 2012). When I tested the application in the same server using IE11 it works fine, but the problem appears when I want to use these app parts from client machines. Other important information, my Web Api services are hosted in a different IIS server where Sharapoint 2013 is hosted.

Web API service: Windows Server 2008 with II7 (srvurbde01)
Sharepoint 2013: Windows Server 2012  (srvurbde05)

I would like to  know what I can check  to solve this issue, because it is very odd that IE11 works in the same server, but not from clients machines.

As you can see in  the pictures this simple sentence does not work in the clients machines using  IE11. IT works with Chrome and Firefox.

$.getJSON("service web root", function (obj) {

var tags = eval(obj);

});

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me

Comment: You'll probably get more feedback on the Sharepoint SE site.